# How does Protection Devotion (good cleric) affect Protection Devotion (evil cleric)?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, feats, cleric

I am running a campaign with clerics, wizards and shadowcasters.

One of the heroes, Cleric (good) has the Protection Devotion feat .

I intend to field a Cleric (Evil)aganist BG who will use Protection Devotion and control undead.

The problem lies in how this feat works with other feat:

> PROTECTION DEVOTION [DOMAIN]
>
> You exude an aura that protects you and those around you. Benefit:
> Once per day as an immediate action, you can activate a protective
> aura. While it is active, you gain a +2 sacred (if your deity is good
> or neutral) or profane (if your deity is evil) bonus to AC, as does
> every ally within 30 feet of you. This bonus increases by 1 for every
> four character levels you possess (maximum +7 at 20th level). This
> effect lasts for 1 minute.
>
> Special: You can select this feat multiple times, gaining one
> additional daily use each time you take it.
>
> Special: If you have the ability to turn or rebuke undead, you gain
> one additional daily use of this feat for each three daily turn or
> rebuke uses you expend.

(*Complete Champion pg. 61*)

Does the protective aura that the good or neutral cleric generates from this feat somehow interfere with the protective aura from the evil cleric when they come into contact?

Are there any corruption throws or can both auras cancel each other out?

Comment: Are these characters allies, or opponents? It’s not clear if you’re the DM “fielding” an evil cleric against the party, or another player who’s just going to be an evil cleric.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

The feat does what it says; there isn’t any more information about it hiding anywhere. There’s plenty of instances of opposing effects negating one another, e.g. any light or darkness spells, but Wizards of the Coast did not choose to use such language in the text of Protection Devotion.

If the two clerics oppose one another, it just means that both sides have a +2 AC bonus.

If the two clerics are allies, then the two auras stack: for those within the overlap between the two areas, the good cleric’s sacred bonus to AC is a different type than the evil cleric’s profane bonus to AC.